# Using email to update SQL database

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use email to update mysql table?

for example I have someone send email which have today article with the image as an attachment and it have to send to particular email address (eg: abc@something.org) to be able to process data to sql table, other address will not work for updating.

Once it receive, it automatically proceed and update sql from the article it receive.

How is it work?
is there any open source that may help this process

Comment: You'd need a mail server which can forward email to a script directly or via a .forward/pipe mechanism, or a script that checks a mailbox at regular intervals. What happens when spammers get hold of this address and flood your article database with penis pill popping russian bride lottery winner "articles"?

Answer (score 3):

Not by sql, you have to involve some sort of programming language which have a subset of methods to communicate with the database and that can receive and send email.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Sendgrid (at http://sendgrid.com): they have a parse API (see http://wiki.sendgrid.com/doku.php?id=parse_api for details) that basically lets you convert an email into an HTTP POST. So if you already have a web page that can update the MySQL database you can just modify it to comply with their spec, set up a sub domain that forwards to Sendgrid and then setup a Sendgrid endpoint that takes any email to that sub domain and posts it to your web page.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application.  If you're using a framework like Wordpress, there are plenty of plugins available to integrate (e.g. Postie).  If you have your own custom application, you may find an open source script to download the new messages, but you'll have to implement your own code to update your database.